# Change the directory where the SQLite *.db-journal file is created

Tags: sqlite, freepascal

Good day,

I have a small application created in Lazarus / Free Pascal. If I run this application located in a folder on my computer, it will start and SQLite will create a temporary file **.db-journal** in the current directory. Since the application is portable, it will also run from a flash drive. And now comes the problem. Some computers (eg at work) do not allow writing to external media. Therefore, when I start the application, it does not start and an error is displayed that it is not possible to open the database (tested on a locked SD card). And so that the application does not always have to be copied to the computer, I would like to know if it is possible to redirect the creation of a temporary file **.db-journal** to another directory, for example the "C:\WINDOWS\USERS<user>" user directory. Is it usually possible to write there always?

Of course, I searched the net, but so far I have not found anything that would help me, so I am addressing you here. Thank you for your advice or guidance.

Jirka

Comment: AFAIK, the journal file is always written to the same directory as the database file. But you can disable journalling at the risk of data loss when writing to the database, or if your database is read-only.

Comment: I don't think it should matter. If it is not possible to write to an external medium, new records will not be saved and the database will be opened only for reading already saved records. I have read several times that SQLite is ideal for distribution on CDs, for example. And in that case, journaling is probably also disabled.

Do you know where to disable it? I tried to load the database in DB Browser for SQLite and switch in PRAGMA tab "Journal Mode" to "Off". After saving and reopening, there is still the "Delete" option.

Comment: The only journal mode that's persistent is WAL. Others have to be set each time you open the database with [`PRAGMA journal_mode`](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode). Or you can open it in read-only mode.